# How could I let a date attribute filter by year in layer navigation?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

As the title describe, I want my product has a date attribute(ex. the date this product begin in stock).

And I can filter the products using this attribute's year. For example, if there are 2 products in 2013-09-08 & 2014-10-10, the filter will show two options 2013 and 2014.

Currently I think I can create another attribute to save the year data, but I'm not sure how to set this attribute not show when I create a new product and how do I write in the value when I save this product.

Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set year as a drop down attribute with the setting use in layered navigation set to yes.

Comment: I knew this but according to this way there will be two attributes: publish date & publish year.
Can I let the admin just enter the date once?

Comment: publish date wouldn't be  type drop down but publish year needs to be a drop down for it to be included in layered navigation. It might just be cleaner to have separate fields for the two.

Edit: You could write an observer for before save of the product through admin and in that select the publish year attribute for the admin without them having to do it.

Comment: Hi I have using observer and it looks work now, thanks!